# mod_rewrite: redirect top level directories to a file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to redirect all top level directories to a file using mod_rewrite.

So the following should redirect there:

```
- http://example.com/test
- http://example.com/test8/ 
- http://example.com/test_9231/
```

The following should NOT redirect there:

```
- http://example.com/test.php
- http://example.com/test_9231/test/
- http://example.com/test/test.php
- http://example.com/test_9231/test
```

None of the directories will physically exist. Directory names will only contain these characters: `A-Za-z0-9_-`

I tried this `RewriteRule /(.*) /index.php [L]` but subdirectories are still redirected.
I thought adding a slash after the 2nd parenthesis would do the job, but it just broke the redirecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+/?$ /index.php
```

This will match a slash, then a name according to your spec, then another optional slash, then end of string, so subdirectories won't match

Comment: are you doing this in .htaccess? Do you have other rewrite rules?

Comment: Yes, in .htaccess. I do have other rules, but I tested your code without them and I get the same result.

Comment: OK, in .htaccess you need to remove the first "/", making it this:

RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+/?$ /index.php

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+/?$ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Yeah, didn't bother to catch the '.', as I assumed either a file would exists or you'd want to create a nice 404 page in PHP itself (I would, nobody is helped with generic 404's, a nice page with hints and / or searchform would be preferable IMHO). That was not the question though, so indeed, doesn't fit the bill.